# WCF Data Service oData Throw Exception from QueryInterceptor

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I have a situation where a user in a specific role is allowed to view the entire contents of an oData feed, while users without that role are allowed to view 'their' records.

The model contains a UserId field. Note: this is for an internal intranet site using the built in AD role provider. Users not in a specific role are allowed to view any record where their User Id matches the value of the UserId field. In the case where an individual without the specific role tries to access records where those values do not match, I'd like to throw a Not Authorized exception.

Ultimately it would seem the expression that is returned by the QueryInterceptor is turned in to SQL later and used to filter the results. Meaning that a throw statement doesn't really make sense inside the expression.

Is there another way to do what I want?

Example of one of my query interceptors:

```
[QueryInterceptor("Notifications")]
public Expression<Func<Notification, bool>> OnQueryNotifications()
{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    var userId = user.Identity.UserId(); //Extension method

    // returns boolean if the user is in any of the roles passed in the array
    var allowed = SiteSecurity.Allowed(user, new string[] { "Administrator", "Technician" });

    if (!allowed)
        // Here is where I need to test if the user is requesting any specific 
        // records, and if they are allowed to view those records.
        return q => q.UserId.Equals(userId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    else
        return q => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either just exclude records by only returning the ones they've access to (as you're doing above).

Alternatively you can return a 403 forbidden status code if a user attempts to get data they've do not have access to.